# using intersection observer in nextjs to change css variable, not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I have some hex colors coming in from a CMS that i need to set some css custom variable to. These should update depending on what section the user is intersecting. I'm using intersection observer to track the section but the css variables only set for 1 out of 3 of the variables i need to change i.e "background". The foreground and highlight variable don't update. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my component - each "season" is a section

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ReactSVG } from 'react-svg'


const Season = ({ season, divider }) => {
// Data from CMS
const { seasonVideo,
seasonTitleSvg,
seasonNumber,
hexSeasonBg,
seasonTextColor,
highlightTextColor,
seasonMessage } = season.fields

const [highlight, setHighlight] = useState(highlightTextColor);
const [foreground, setForeground] = useState(seasonTextColor);
const [background, setBackground] = useState(hexSeasonBg);


useEffect(() => {
   const options = {
      root: null, // Use the viewport as the root
      rootMargin: '0px', // No margin
      threshold: 0.4, // 40% visibility required to trigger the intersection
    };
   const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection, options);
   observer.observe(document.querySelector(`.${seasonNumber}`));
   return () => {
     observer.disconnect();
   };
 }, [seasonNumber, foreground, background, highlight]);


// Function to handle intersection
const handleIntersection = (entries) => {
   entries.forEach((entry) => {
     if (entry.isIntersecting) {

      console.log(foreground, background, entry)

         document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background', background);
         document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--highlight', highlight);
         document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--foreground', foreground);
     } else {
     }
   });
 };

return (
<section className={`${seasonNumber} season`}>
      <div className="seasonTitle-wrapper">
            <div className="season-title">
               <ReactSVG src={'https:' + seasonTitleSvg.fields.file.url} style={{ width: '30vw', height: 'auto' }} alt={seasonNumber} />
            </div>
            <ReactSVG src={'https:' + divider} className="divider" />
      </div>
</section>
)
}

export default Season
```

Comment: How does the seasonNumber look like? What value does it have?

Comment: value is "s3", "s2" and so fourth

Comment: can you try setting the property of --background, --higlight, --foreground according to the season number? something like: "setProperty(`--background-${seasonNumber}`, background)".
I think your issue is that you are overriding the property every time the season renders. So the actual value of the css variable will be only the last one.

Note: I am commenting and not answering because I don't have much time to test it on my own machine.

Comment: how would i refer it in css then?

Comment: Did  you try it? Does it work? I just want to know if we are on the right direction.

Comment: so i have added that adjustment an now it creates/updates a css variable with that dynamic name everytime there is a an intersection